# How to fix the slide width size in swiper.js?

Tags: swiper.js

I'm using swiper.js in my Next.js project. I've an slider with dynamic slide number. inside each slide I've put a component which has a fixed width. My problem is my slides are not centered inside my Slider. also when I slide to right and it reaches the end of my slides there is a big gap from left.[image: this is image for my slider. each slide has a white background to show you the width of it]

I want my slide to have a fixed width and be centered in my slider. also in big screens when there is more than 1 slide showing I don't want that gap from left side. I tried to set the slide width manually but it didn't work. I also tried centeredSlice prop on Slider.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the slider in a div(container) and specify the width of the container. Also, give 100% width for the swiper container.

```html
<section className="z-10 flex flex-col w-full">
  <Swiper className="w-full">
    <SwiperSlide className="bg-black">your content</SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
</section>
```